# How to capitalize number in a persons name?

Tags: capitalization, names

When refering to a king with a number in his name, say *richard the second*, how should one capitalize that.

Should it be:

1. Richard the second
2. Richard the Second
3. Richard The Second

Or something else?

Comment: Typically we write (as opposed to speak) the name *Richard II*.

Comment: @DanBron - Is spelling it out considered incorrect?

Comment: I guess I'll turn that question around and ask: what's your motivation for spelling it out, rather than using the conventional nomenclature?

Comment: @DanBron - I want a way that looks closer to the way it is commonly spoken.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Elizabeth+II%2CElizabeth+the+second%2C+Richard+the+second%2C+Richard+II&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CElizabeth%20II%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BElizabeth%20II%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BELIZABETH%20II%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CElizabeth%20the%20second%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BElizabeth%20the%20Second%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BELIZABETH%20THE%20SECOND%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BElizabeth%20the%20second%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CRichard%20the%20second%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BRichard%20the%20Second%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRichard%20the%20second%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRICH

Comment: That ngram shows the Roman numeral version far more common as @DanBron says.

Answer (score 2):

"Richard the Second" (your number 2) is perfectly correct. Have a look at this: http://www.sirbacon.org/graphics/richard2.gif

Comment: Well done for finding that - but it was in 1615!  What was correct then may not be correct now.

Comment: It is still correct.

Comment: Not according to the ngram cited above.

Comment: ngram is a measure of frequency, not of correctness. Anyway, you forgot to put in "Richard the Second" (thus capitalized).

Comment: I didn't do the ngram - I just looked at the one cited above.  I agree that "ngram is a measure of frequency, not of correctness" - but who determines 'correctness' in these circumstances?  What is your basis for saying "It is still correct."?

Comment: In English, as in most languages, correctness is dictated by the usage of good authors. For example, Shakespeare. Which brings us back to my answer.